# Why I cannot define a Simple Struct with Safe + Send features enabled

Tags: rust

This could be a very basic Rust question, I am trying to create a **mut static object** inside a mod. And to do that I need to implement a Lazy construct but I am not understanding why I cannot create a Lazy construct for my simple struct:

```
pub struct S {
    a_: String,
}
impl S {
    pub fn new(a: String) -> Self {
        S {
            a_: a
        }
    }
    pub fn foo(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.a_);
    }
}
unsafe impl Sync for S {}
unsafe impl Send for S {}
```

```
I am getting errors like:

`error[E0277]: `Cell<Option<fn() -> S>>` cannot be shared between threads safely    --> src/main.rs:26:15
    | 26  |     static X: Lazy<S> = Lazy::new(|| {
    |               ^^^^^^^ `Cell<Option<fn() -> S>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `once_cell::unsync::Lazy<S>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `Cell<Option<fn() -> S>>`
    = note: if you want to do aliasing and mutation between multiple threads, use `std::sync::RwLock` note: required because it appears within the type `Lazy<S>`    --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/once_cell-1.19.0/src/lib.rs:714:16
    | 714 |     pub struct Lazy<T, F = fn() -> T> {
    |                ^^^^
    = note: shared static variables must have a type that implements `Sync``
```

First I tried to define the struct `S` without the custom impl's:

```
unsafe impl Sync for S {}
unsafe impl Send for S {}
```

But it didn't work. As in the below code I am adding them back but no results.

```
fn main() {
    let s = s_mod::S::new("10".to_string());
    s.foo();
}

mod s_mod {
    use once_cell::unsync::Lazy;

    pub struct S {
        a_: String,
    }
    impl S {
        pub fn new(a: String) -> Self {
            S {
                a_: a
            }
        }
        pub fn foo(&self) {
            println!("{}", self.a_);
        }
    }
    unsafe impl Sync for S {}
    unsafe impl Send for S {}
    
    static X: Lazy<S> = Lazy::new(|| {
       let s = S::new("4".to_string());
       s
    });
}
```

What am I missing here? Can someone help me understand?

Comment: never impl sync and send yourself unless you are std or a lib that do smart point

Comment: @Stargateur I won't. But how to create a mut global object in Rust anyways - this is just a basic requirement.

Comment: if you want sync what about use sync version of lazy ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=66f8f8578ac3610ffe9844f86e636b2f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`once_cell::unsync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/unsync/struct.Lazy.html) cannot be shared across threads (as implied by the `unsync`).

You should use [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) instead.

Your struct itself being `Sync` is insufficient as it is wrapped inside of this type.

Comment: wow! Unbelievable.

Comment: @kishoredbn: That's what IDE auto imports do to you sometimes :).